# Docker Port Issue bind: cannot assign requested address

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I get the following error when trying to run:

```
docker-compose up
```

Error:

```
dataserver    | time="2019-10-13T16:32:41Z" level=info msg="Listening on http://192.168.100.36:5055"
dataserver    | time="2019-10-13T16:32:41Z" level=fatal msg="listen tcp 192.168.100.36:5055: bind: cannot assign requested address"
dataserver exited with code 1
```

Nothing is running on port 5055 on the ***Windows 10*** laptop, so that's out. So my question is what is causing the error, and what's a solution to it?

---

Extra Info:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: dataserver-db
    container_name: dataserver-db
    restart: "no"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.database
    networks:
      - network1
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=product
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: dataserver-db
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
        read_only: false

  dataserver:
    image: dataserver
    container_name: dataserver
    restart: "no"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - network1
    ports:
      - "5055:5055"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        # source: /home/user/settings.json
        source: C:/user/settings.json
        target: /app/settings.json
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        # source: /home/user/control/inbox/
        source: C:/user/product/control/Inbox/
        target: /app/inbox/
        read_only: false

volumes:
  dataserver-db:
    name: dataserver-db

networks:
  network1:
    external:
      name: network1_dataserver
```

Note: I'm still new to Docker so if anything else is needed to debug, let me know, and I'll get it to you. And this is different than the "duplicate" because it's a Windows 10 machine and the port is available according to the windows app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I got error in run time that "Cannot assign requested address" in C under Linux (Centos)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799216/i-got-error-in-run-time-that-cannot-assign-requested-address-in-c-under-linux)

Comment: @Adiii Nope, not a duplicate. The port is available and this is also a Windows 10 computer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that ended up working was to choose a different port. This seemed to work. I changed it to 5050.